# runtimeError (invalid strategy some_external_strategy)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, google-calendar-api, omniauth, warden

I have been trying for eternity to get my rails app to use google sign-in and calendars to no avail. I can get the google sign in page but when after I enter my password I get a runtime error when using the calendar. When I try the google auth path I get a different error. I am still able to get the the google sign in screen but I get a 'client secret missing error' even though I have it entered in the application.yml and in device.rb. Not sure what info to add because I am a newbie here. 
my error:

> Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-22 12:10:07 -0700 Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"hw+HZafhIkLohmPvpVdtegQtctmLDX9vCFa2HHoYJTMcFQi7yhaq3Cq/1+NJpTAEbY+Un9GIVc8AoGZxiE2A2g==", "user"=>{"email"=>"Hodari@giddengeniusproject.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"} Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 28ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

RuntimeError (Invalid strategy some_external_strategy):    warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/proxy.rb:371:in `_fetch_strategy' warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/proxy.rb:355:in`block in _run_strategies_for' warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/proxy.rb:354:in `each' warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/proxy.rb:354:in`_run_strategies_for' warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/proxy.rb:324:in `_perform_authentication' warden (1.2.7) lib/warden/proxy.rb:128:in`authenticate!' devise (4.2.1) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:17:in `create' ac

> ### "

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies [:omniauth, :params]
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_into_session do |user|
  user.persistence_token
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_from_session do |id|
  User.where(persistence_token: id).first
end
#
module UserCredentialAuthentication
  def verify_against_old_credentials( user, password )
    Sha512.matches?( user.sha512_password, password, user.sha512_salt )
  end

  def transition_from_sha512!( user, password )
    user.password = password
    user.sha512_password = nil
    user.sha512_salt = nil
    user.save
  end

  def authenticate!
    Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] Authenticating user #{username} from #{medium}")
    user = User.find_by_username_or_email(username)

    if user.blank?
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] No Such User")
      fail "Invalid email or password"

    elsif user.sha512_password.not.blank? && verify_against_old_credentials( user, password )
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] User #{user.email} authenticated with a SHA512 password.")
      transition_from_sha512!( user, password )
      success! user

    elsif user.password_digest && user.authenticate( password )
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] User #{user.email} authenticated with a password.")
      success! user

    else
      Rails.logger.warn("[AUTH] Bad Password")
      fail "Invalid email or password"

    end
  end
end


Warden::Strategies.add(:omniauth) do
  include UserCredentialAuthentication

  def medium
    'omniauth'
  end

  def valid?
    Rails.logger.warn("[OMNIAUTH] checking omniauth")
    auth.provided? && auth.basic?
  end

  def username
    auth.credentials[0]
  end

  def password
    auth.credentials[1]
  end

  def auth
    @omniauth ||= Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(env)
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:params) do
  include UserCredentialAuthentication

  def medium
    'params'
  end

  def valid?
    Rails.logger.warn("[OMNIAUTH] checking params")
    credential_params['username'] && credential_params['password']
  end

  def username
    credential_params['username']
  end

  def password
    credential_params['password']
  end

  def credential_params
    p = params.blank? ? post_params : params
    p['user_session'] || {}
  end

  def post_params
    @post_params ||= get_post_params
  end

  def get_post_params
    if( request.post? )
      begin
        body = request.body.read
        request.body.rewind
        JSON.parse( body )
      end
    else
      {}
    end
  end
end

> "
>
```

> ```
>  #class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
>   # You should configure your model like this:
>    #devise :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google]
>
>   # You should also create an action method in this controller like this:
>   # def twitter
>   # end
>
>   def google_oauth2
>       # You need to implement the method below in your model (e.g. app/models/user.rb)
>       @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])
>       sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
>       set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Google Oauth2")
>       if is_navigational_format?
>
>       if @user.persisted?
>         flash[:notice] = I18n.t 'devise.omniauth_callbacks.success', kind: 'Google'
>         sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
>       else
>         session['devise.google_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth'].except(:extra) # Removing extra as it can
> ```
>
> overflow some session stores
>               redirect_to new_user_registration_url, alert: @user.errors.full_messages.join("\n")
>             end
>           end
>
> ```
>   # GET|POST /resource/auth/google
>   # def passthru
>   #   super
>   #   render status: 404, plain: "Not found. Authentication passthru."
>   # end
>   #
>   # GET|POST /users/auth/google/callback
>   # def failure
>   #   super
>   # end
>   #
>   # protected
>   #
>   # #The path used when OmniAuth fails
>    def after_omniauth_failure_path_for(google_oauth2)
>      redirect_to root_path
>     super(:user)
>   end
>   end
> end
> ```

session controller

> class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController   #
>   before_action :configure_sign_in_params, only: [:create]   # include
>   Accessible   # skip_before_action :check_user, only: :destroy
>
> # GET /resource/sign_in   # def new   #   super   # end POST
>   /resource/sign_in   def create
>       user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
>       session[:user_id] = user.id
>       redirect_to root_path
>       super   end
>
> DELETE /resource/sign_out   def destroy
>       session[:user_id] = nil
>       redirect_to root_path
>       super   end

Comment: What's in your `sessions_controller#create`?

Comment: hi @SebastiánPalma thank you for your reply, my create actions is:          def create
    user = User.from_omniauth(env["omniauth.auth"])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to root_path
    super
  end